# GlueContext write_dynamic_frame fails after adding BucketOwnerFullControl configuration

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, aws-glue

I am trying to write dataframe into different account s3 bucket as json output.
The following code is failing with S3 Access denied error in GLUE Spark Streaming job. But If I run the code without first line in following code, it works and output it written into S3 bucket

```
glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame=dynamic_df, connection_type="s3",
                                                     connection_options={"path": output_path},
                                                     format=file_format, transformation_ctx="datasink")
```

Here is the error log:

> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
> Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
> AccessDenied; Request ID: W52125NY7G3EF7WH; S3 Extended Request ID:
> 4t9JOJedv2qNRy6W8ySxdQQ7r+TMN1MWpZCFOK1IKO6W4gx4a2oKuK5vwXUPnh4HkkPAG+LnEIc=;
> Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: 4t9JOJedv2qUPnh4HkkPAG+LnEIc= at
> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1819)
> at
> com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1403)
> at

This looks strange to me as Bucket has full permission and it works perfectly when 2nd line alone executed but bucket owner is still glue account which I am trying to change it using `fs.s3.canned.acl`.

The destination bucket also setup with `Bucket owner preferred` option
Please suggest me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to have permission in bucket policies only.

Glue role was missing `s3:PutObjectAcl` permission in IAM.